# My messages aren't sent in the right order in BotFramework - Java

Tags: java, botframework, synchronized

I have two main methods in my main controller, which are :

```
public synchronized void sendQuestion(Activity activity, PostQuestion pq) {
    Map<String, Object> map = allConversations.get(activity.getConversation().getId());
    map.put("command", pq.getQuestionId()); //It will run a command at next user input
    allConversations.put(activity.getConversation().getId(), map); //Store all conversation data
    sendMessage(activity, pq.getQuestionLabel()); //QuestionLabel is a string
}

public boolean sendMessage(Activity activity, String msg) {
    Activity reply = activity.createReply(msg);
    try {
        this.connector.getConversations()
                .sendToConversation(
                        activity.getConversation().getId(),
                        reply);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My bot is a basic QnA bot. It retrieves data from APIs, and send the results. It asks questions after answers.
My problem is :
If I send for example two messages with sendMessage method, and then a message with sendQuestion (who send a message too):

`sendMessage(activity, "Hello");
sendMessage(activity, "World!");
sendQuestion(activity, PostQuestion.askHello())`

it happens sometimes that I have the following order "Message - Question (message) - Message" instead of "Message - Message - Question".

Is my problem about threads ? (I don't do multithreading in my application).
I tried with synchronized keyword for my two methods, but my problem is still here.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: I'm sorry for the wait, yes of course! thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a bot is a web app and you'll be dealing with REST API calls etc., there's really no way to not have asynchrony. For example, every time you use `sendToConversation` to send a message from the bot to the user, that is an asynchronous operation. The Bot Builder Java SDK uses completable futures to handle asynchrony, and you should too. Have a look at the [Welcome User sample](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/blob/master/samples/03.welcome-user/src/main/java/com/microsoft/bot/sample/welcomeuser/WelcomeUserBot.java#L104-L144) to see how completable futures can be used to make sure your asynchronous operations execute one after another, waiting for each one to complete in turn:

```
/**
 * This will prompt for a user name, after which it will send info about the conversation.  After sending
 * information, the cycle restarts.
 *
 * @param turnContext The context object for this turn.
 * @return A future task.
 */
@Override
protected CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageActivity(TurnContext turnContext) {
    // Get state data from UserState.
    StatePropertyAccessor<WelcomeUserState> stateAccessor = userState.createProperty("WelcomeUserState");
    CompletableFuture<WelcomeUserState> stateFuture = stateAccessor.get(turnContext, WelcomeUserState::new);

    return stateFuture.thenApply(thisUserState -> {
        if (!thisUserState.getDidBotWelcomeUser()) {
            thisUserState.setDidBotWelcomeUser(true);

            String userName = turnContext.getActivity().getFrom().getName();
            return turnContext.sendActivities(
                MessageFactory.text(FIRST_WELCOME_ONE),
                MessageFactory.text(String.format(FIRST_WELCOME_TWO, userName))
            );
        } else {
            String text = turnContext.getActivity().getText().toLowerCase();
            switch (text) {
                case "hello":
                case "hi":
                    return turnContext.sendActivities(MessageFactory.text("You said " + text));

                case "intro":
                case "help":
                    return sendIntroCard(turnContext);

                default:
                    return turnContext.sendActivity(WELCOMEMESSAGE);
            }
        }
    })
        // make the return value happy.
        .thenApply(resourceResponse -> null);
}
```

Also remember that the Java SDK is still in preview and so you will risk running into problems even if you do everything right.